# Creating matrix from 3d mesh

Tags: matlab

Initially I had a matrix (512x512), I created a 3d mesh using mesh() function. The figure showed me peaks. I wanted to extract the matrix for each peak and then calculate the volume. I came across two cases for the solution:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/277512-how-to-find-peaks-in-3d-mesh

[Find volume of 3d peaks in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106812/find-volume-of-3d-peaks-in-matlab)

In both cases the data generated in the form of X, Y, Z. This  is however not my case. How can I extract matrices for each peak?

[peaks from 512x512 matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mnnm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a 2-D matrix of Z values. When you plot just the Z matrix via `mesh()`, MATLAB uses the row and column positions of the values in the matrix as the X and Y values. To get explicit X and Y values, you can use `meshgrid()`. For example, assuming your X and Y values range from 1 to 600 as shown in your linked plot:

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:600);

Keep in mind that depending on how you want to use the Z, Y, and Z values, you may have to transform the format further. In your first link, it assumes the data is formatted as 3, 1-D arrays, while in the second link, it assumes the data is formatted as 3, 2-D matrices. If you need the values in a 1-D format, you can transform the 2-D matrices into column vectors via `:`, ie:

```
X_flat = X(:);
Y_flat = Y(:);
Z_flat = Z(:);
```